# Do I need to pay income tax for money earned in the U.S. & transferred to my account in India?

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, india

I have a web site which generates around 10K every month. This amount is directly credited to my bank account from Google USA account. Do I need to pay tax in India? Please advise. I am very new to tax rules.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you a U.S. citizen or resident? You didn't say, and it will be relevant.

Comment: Are you in India or in the US?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you need to pay taxes in India. Show this as other income and pay tax according to your tax bracket. Note you need to pay the taxes quarterly if the net tax payable is more than 10,000.